# Differentiate linetype with multiple lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
Var1           Var2 Freq Week
1       A2 Status Yet to Attempt    9   45
2       A3 Status Yet to Attempt    9   45
3 A4 Udemy Status Yet to Attempt    6   45
4       A5 Status Yet to Attempt    9   45
5       A2 Status Yet to Attempt   11   46
6       A3 Status Yet to Attempt    9   46
7 A4 Udemy Status Yet to Attempt    8   46
8       A5 Status Yet to Attempt   11   46
```

I want to keep this in `geom_line()` and try differentiate with different line type.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=week,y=Freq) + geom_line(aes(col=Var1))..
```

Unfortunately the value of x and y is same for Row 1 and 8. Hence we need change linetype to differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `linetype` as an aesthetic like this:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=week,y=Freq) + geom_line(aes(linetype=Var1))..
```

Since your example data was difficult to input into R, here's an example using the the `mtcars` dataset:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=disp)) + 
    geom_line(aes(linetype=as.factor(cyl)))
```

[image: Example of linetype as an aesthetic]

Answer (score 0):

To set the linetype to a constant value, use the `linetype` geom parameter (e.g., `geom_line(data=d, mapping=aes(x=x, y=y), linetype=3)` sets the linetype of all lines in the layer to 3, which corresponds to a dotted line).

[image]